# open port on azure while logged onto azure vm

Tags: azure, port

I want to open a port on Azure. I am logged onto Azure VM. After that how to do I open the port?

I tried opening the firewall port but that did not help. I also tried to do it thru `azure-cli` but it needs web login.

Can I not open a port while logged in onto that Azure VM?

Comment: I posted an answer on ServerFault [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/737717/unable-to-configure-port-mapping-for-azure-availability-set-in-the-new-portal/737796#737796) which explains/illustrates how to open ports, both with classic and ARM-based VMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VMs in azure service management mode:

1. To open a particular port, say 8080 in your VM, you have to add an endpoint in azure portal, powershell or using xplat-cli. Once this is done, you have created a connectivity between external loadbalancer (I mean VIP of the VM) to the actual VM (with Internal IP address). If the VM is Linux, by default you can start using endpoint (VIP and port) it unless you restrict ports specifically.
2. For windows VM, for non standard ports, you have to add windows firewall inbound allow rules (say for 8080) inside your VM so that it can accept traffic forwarded from VIP

For VMs in azure resource management:

1. You have to first create a loadbalancer with VIP, then add NAT rules to forward traffic from VIP to VM. (use load balancing rules if same VIP port forwards traffic to multiple backend VMs)
2. For windows VM, again windows firewall inbound rules needs to be added

Securing ports:
The above scenario will work by default, but if you want to secure your ports, you have to follow either one of the below, not both.

1. Use Access control List (ACL): This works at VIP endpoint level. If we want to restrict VIP port 8080 to only few Ip and deny other IP, we can use ACL to add those IPs. This can be done in portal endpoint section/powershell/Xplat-cli
2. Use Network Security Group (NSG): This works at pheriphery of VM level. We have greater control here to restrict multiple VM ports, port range, etc., but we have to manage those rules. The ports needs to be secured in NSG is the VM internal port whereas in ACL it is the VIP port.

Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

You also need to open the port in the *Endpoint settings within the Azure Portal*.

Go to `Azure Portal -> Your VM -> Settings -> Endpoints` and add your Port.

Answer (score 0):

To open a port, you have to it from the azure portal and not in the VM. You can use the NSG (Network Security Group) attached to vm and add a rule in the "Inbound security rules"

[image]